# Create a keybinding to call a function using the universal-argument

Tags: key-bindings

Currently I have a short cut to call the function 'helm-ag' (Using evil-leader)

```
 (evil-leader/set-leader ".")
 (evil-leader/set-key "g" 'helm-ag)
```

When 'helm-ag' is called with the Universal-argument (Ctrl - U) it allows me to choose in which directory I'd like to run the command. I use this all the time so I'd like to create a permanent short to specifically run the 'helm-ag' with the universal argument.

I've tried this:

```
(evil-leader/set-key "g" '(lambda () (interactive)(universal-argument)(helm-ag))
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
(evil-leader/set-key
 "g"
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (setq current-prefix-arg '(4))
   (helm-ag)))
```

Comment: You're right. Please update your answer with the complete command and I'll be glad to mark it as the right answer. (evil-leader/set-key "g" '(lambda () (interactive)(setq current-prefix-arg '(4))(helm-ag)))

Comment: I haven't tried but the following should also work: `(lambda () (interactive) (helm-ag 4))`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, it doesn't since `helm-ag` literally checks for `current-prefix-arg`.

Answer (score 0):

For searchers:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-s")
                (lambda (&optional arg)
                  (interactive "P")
                  (my-nested-function-with-C-u-logic arg)))
```